# How can I check if a specific column has a specific value in a List(Of Class) based on another List(Of Class)?

Tags: vb.net

Think of Stackoverflow tags for this example. Let's say I have two classes:

```
Public Class SelectedTags

    Public Property TagID As Integer
        Get ...
        Set ...
    End Property

    Public Property Name As String
        Get ...
        Set ...
    End Property

End Class


Public Class AllTags

    Public Property TagID As Integer
        Get ...
        Set ...
    End Property

    Public Property Name As String
        Get ...
        Set ...
    End Property

    Public Property Selected As Boolean
        Get ...
        Set ...
    End Property
    Private _Selected As Boolean = False

End Class
```

So if I have an object, let's say a car. The first class above, SelectedTags would contain only the tags that have been selected for this car.

The second class is already constructed, with a default value of ***False*** for ***Selected***.

What I need to return to my app is the **AllTags** data, but I need to set the **Selected** property based on if **TagID** exists in **SelectedTags**. I feel I'm going about this wrong with several nested for each loops...

Pseudo Logic:

```
For Each Tag In AllTags
    If Tag.TagID can be found in SelectedTags Then
        Update this one and set Selected = True
    End If        
End For
```

Getting a little confused with examples of Linq, and using .Contains, .Find, .Function(), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your classes doesn't make a lot of sense.  You called them `SelectedTags` and `AllTags` even though the each only store data for a single tag.  So, for the purposes of my answer, I will call them `Tag` and `SelectableTag`, respectively:

```
Public Class Tag
    Public Property TagID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Public Class SelectableTag
    Public Property TagID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Selected As Boolean = False
End Class
```

I will then assume that you have two lists declared like this:

```
Dim tags As New List(Of Tag)()
Dim selectableTags As New List(Of SelectableTag)()
```

Given that setup, you can do what you wish with a nested loop like this:

```
For Each selecableTag As SelectableTag In selectableTags
    For Each tag as Tag in tags
        If tag.TagID = selectableTag.TagID Then
            selectableTag.Selected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End For
```

However, as you suggested, the same could be accomplished using LINQ.  For instance, LINQ provides the `Any` extension method:

```
For Each selecableTag As SelectableTag In selectableTags
    selectableTag.Selected = tags.Any(Function(x) x.TagID = selectableTag.TagID)
End For
```

Comment: Right, your nested loop is exactly what I was doing. Apologies for the lack of sense the classes make. Given my unique setup on what I'm doing it's necessary, but hard to explain. My goal was to have it more optimized, and it appears you have exactly what I need.. Trying the Linq now.

Comment: Worked perfectly with Linq. Do you think this is more effective than the nested loop? The nested loop seemed overkill, but perhaps this is doing the same thing behind the scenes?

Comment: Yes. It's essentially doing the same thing behind the scenes. LINQ is generally nothing more than a shortcut which helps to keep the code short and more readable, but there's nothing inherently wrong with the nested loop method.

Answer (score 0):

This will find each selected tag in AllTags and set it to true, which I think is what you're asking.

```
For Each SelectedTag As SelectedTags In SelectedTagsList
  For Each Tag As AllTags In AllTagsList
    If Tag.TagID = SelectedTag.TagID Then
      'Found the right tag
      Tag.Selected = True
      Exit For 'No need to keep going in this loop
    End If
  Next
Next
```

This could be accomplished a better way by having a list(of AllTags) and then when building the list of selected tags, just build another list(of AllTags), and add the AllTags as references. Then you can alter that selected value and it would be reflected in both lists. This means you won't have to loop through each one and compare it to the selected list, and you don't need a separate class for selected tags if they are going to be identical in structure to AllTags

```
Dim AllTagsList As New List(Of AllTags)
AllTagsList.Add(New AllTags())

Dim selectedTags As New List(Of AllTags)
selectedTags.Add(AllTagsList(0)) 'This is a reference to the first item in the AllTagsList

selectedTags(0).Selected = True 'Changing this value changes it for both lists

Dim outcome As Boolean = AllTagsList(0).Selected 'This will also be true now
```

This example shows how you can alter the reference in the selected list and have it reflected in the original list. without looping through anything.

Hopefully this is helpful to you, I'm not sure I understood what you are doing exactly.